# Why are we still stuck on this function despite threading?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I want to make a function that waits for input, and if nothing is input in 2 seconds, skips the input and moves on to the rest of the function.

I tried this function from another thread:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

answer = None

def check():
    time.sleep(2)
    if answer != None:
        return "ayy"
    print("Too slow")
    return "No input"

Thread(target = check).start()

answer = input("Input something: ")
print(answer)
```

This code asks for input, and if no input is added in 2 seconds it prints "too slow". However it never moves on to print(answer), I think it keeps waiting for user input.

I want to ask for user input and if it takes too long, it just takes input = None and moves on to the functions underneath it. I looked at timeout methods involving signal, but that's only for linux and im on a windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right. The `input()` call is waiting for the user to submit any input which in your case never happens.

A cross platform solution would be to make use of `select()`:

```
import sys
import select

def timed_input(prompt, timeout=10):
    """
    Wait ``timeout`` seconds for user input

    Returns a tuple:
        [0] -> Flag if timeout occured
        [1] -> User input
    """
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    input, output, error = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 2)

    if input:
        return True, sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    else:
        return False, None

timed_input('Input something: ', timeout=2)
```

That's a dirty prototype. I suggest to use exceptions for the timeout or a more intuitive return value for the function.